# Is there any way to combine a folder picker and a file picker in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp

I want the user to be able to select both files and folder in a picker dialog. Is it achievable in UWP?

The only way around this that I can think of is to create a flyout menu for the browse button that allows you to choose a folder or file item to pick then opens the corresponding dialog. But I want the user to decide after the dialog is shown or even choose both files and folders at the same time.

Should I just include the old OpenFileDialog? It seems like the wrong way to go about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want the user to be able to select both files and folder in a picker dialog. Is it achievable in UWP?

As far as I know, it is not possible now in traditional UWP app. When your call the file/folder picker in your app, it calls a single, unified interface to let user pick files/folder from the files system or from other apps. As we know, UWP apps work in sandbox(app container), file/folder pickers break this container by using brokers, this is handled by system.

But it's just in traditional UWP app, there is method now to use Win32 APIs in UWP app if your app won't be published to Store. If you are interested in this method, you can refer to [Brokered Windows Runtime Components for side-loaded Windows Store apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/brokered-windows-runtime-components-for-side-loaded-windows-store-apps).

Our suggestion is that you may submit a request to add this new features for developing through the Windows Feedback tool.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I will indeed submit a request for this feature.